# Mongoid 5: find_one_and_update with returnNewDocument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, mongoid5

Is it possible, that Mongoid, v5.1.2 ignores the `returnNewDocument` option when used with `find_one_and_update`?

Consider the following code:

```
next_number = TrackingId.where(id: id).find_one_and_update({
    :$inc => {
      auto_increment_counter: 1
    }
  },
  upsert: true,
  returnNewDocument: true
).auto_increment_counter
```

where `auto_increment_counter` is an Integer `field :auto_increment_counter, type: Integer, default: 0` on that class.

However, when no document is found, it creates one, but it doesn't return the newly created document. So I get `nil` back from `find_one_and_update` and it breaks.

Comment: looking at the docs, it should given your `upsert: true` param.  Looks like a bug to me...

Comment: This is not a bug, please see the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suspect that mongoid implementation of find_one_and_update would change the flag of returnNewDocument to return_new_document or $returnNewDocument. I will take a look at the mongoid code base later on and confirm.

Update: So I had a play in pry and looked at the code. I later was able to confirm this in the docs as well. The option you are looking for is return_document, which you set to either :before or :after (see docs: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid%2FContextual%2FMongo%3Afind_one_and_update)

Therefore your query should be:

```
next_number = TrackingId.where(id: id).find_one_and_update({
    :$inc => {
      auto_increment_counter: 1
    }
  },
  upsert: true,
  return_document: :after
).auto_increment_counter
```

Comment: I wonder what the logic behind naming the argument `return_document` and not `return_new_document` as in mongodb is.

Comment: because their implementation has made the decision to use the return_document to be a before/after flag rather than assuming that a document that is returned will be the one before the update. This way it's more explicit than the mongodb api in what to expect it to return.